# Tf package extrapolation to the past

Tags: transform, ros

When I lookup for transform like below,

```
(trans, rot) = self.listener.lookupTransform(\
                    self.robot_link, target_link, rospy.Time(0))
```

Error pops up:`Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.`

However, when I change this line to

```
(trans, rot) = self.listener.lookupTransform(\
                    self.robot_link, target_link, rospy.Time.now())
```

Error processing request: `Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the transformation to become available for a specific duration as described in the [tf and Time ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20(Python)):

```
now = rospy.Time.now()
listener.waitForTransform(self.robot_link, target_link, now, rospy.Duration(4.0))
(trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform(self.robot_link, target_link, now)
```

This blocks and waits for your specified duration until the transform you want to query is available.

You might want to add some handling of the case that the transform does not get published in the wait duration.

Comment: Thank you for your info. The error still exists. It looks a bit odd.

Comment: [ERROR] [1576882805.392447]: Error processing request: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1576882790.391376019 but the latest data is at time 1576882777.683639288, when looking up transform from frame [tool/hamer_pickup_link] to frame [base_link]

Comment: You can try waiting for longer than 4 seconds maybe?
How often does this transform get published? TF keeps transformation data for 10 seconds before discarding it, if the transformation is getting published irregularly it might not be in the TF tree anymore.
If the transformation is getting published and received by two different machines make sure their clocks are in sync. I'm not sure if that should produce an error like this but it's worth testing for.